# Datatables is acting differently on different screen resolutions

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, responsive-design, datatables

My datatable has many entries, and also have child tables on each row of the main table.

I am implementing this kind of action into my table, just with a few changes so it is a table inside the child row.
https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html

I have this problem that when I run my page that has the datatables is shows different things on different resolution. On 1080p is works as intended where it shows the button where if you click you would see the child table, but if I execute the page on a smaller resolution it would not show that button. Picture shows how the button disappears on a lower resolution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB8Qs.png)

Comment: I think you are just using `Row_Detail` functionality. If you want to target multiple screens, then you have to use [Responsive](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) extension of DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense that database acting differently for different resolutions. Take a look at your ui or backend layer. For different resolutions, ui should behaves differently so you may have different business logic for different resolutions.

For example when the button is shown then an init action for this button may have trigger a query. The very opposite, when the button is not shown then the query may have not working and data does not loaded. It is up to your logic. Take a look at your implementation.

Comment: It is basically implementing the Datatable plug-in into a table tag, there is not really more implementation happening, except for the Datatables own implementation.

Comment: I see. It is possible to debug the plug-in? There should be a bug then.

Comment: Yir, just a weird thing, never seeing anything like this.